# How can I tell if a symbol was used as a key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm exploring ES6 symbols, trying to understand what they are and I cannot wrap my head around this behavior

```
> let sym = Symbol()
> let a = {}
> a[sym]= "value"
'value'
> a
{}
> Object.keys(a)
[]
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
[]
> a[sym]
'value'
> a[Symbol()]
undefined
> JSON.stringify(sym)
undefined
> JSON.stringify(a)
'{}'
> sym
Symbol()
```

I'm not understanding symbols yet, but Where is the key and value hiding?!? Did java script fall into the realm of witchcraft and wizardry? Is there anyway to tell it is there at all?

EDIT::

Thank you for notifying me about  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols();

So with ES6 I have to check Object.getOwnPropertyNames() and  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols() for hidden non enumerable properties?

Comment: Not sure if this helps : "A symbol is a unique and immutable data type and may be used as an identifier for object properties. The symbol object is an implicit object wrapper for the symbol primitive data type." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: So a superposition of both existing and not existing?  howbout renaming symbols to SchrödingerCats()

Comment: You can get them with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(a)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) it looks like you can get them with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(a)`.

I stumbled across this article which provides some additional context: 
http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/

> Symbols give a whole new sense of purpose to Objects - they provide a kind of hidden under layer to Objects - not iterable over, not fetched using the already existing Reflection tools and guaranteed not to conflict with other properties in the object!

Comment: It might be nice if they added a method to loop over both, e.g. `Object.getOwnProperties()', and leave the other two for the cases where you just want one or the other